# notification bubble badge in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, css

how to get the notification number badge in ajax like Facebook. cant post a picture here but i think people know what am i talking about. its like when you log in to Facebook, if you have new messages you will get a little number on the top right corner of the icons next to search bar. i'm currently found this piece of code in charge of creating that number but i cant go any further from that. here is the code i found.

```
<span class="jewelCount" id="notificationsCountWrapper">
    <span id="notificationsCountValue">1</span>
    <i class="accessible_elem"> Notifications</i>
</span>
```

Comment: i want to know how to do that

Comment: We cant help you with this much of information .. please provide some more info .. Anyways you can have look at this http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/jquery-notification-menu/

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to use plugin :)

Comment: In that case you have do to lots of coding according to your requirement ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like that?

Here is the css & jquery solution, if you like. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/DfSda/1/

Add `<span class="ballons"></span>` inside your button, and replace the dynamic count value.

```
.ballons {
    float:right;
    margin:-20px 8px 0 0;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
```